# Embed dynamically updated blog RSS Feed to Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, rss

I have a website on one domain, and a blog hosted on blogspot. at the bottom of the homepage on my website, I want to embed a link to the latest post on my blogspot along with the respective article image and title. I have a function that used to work but since i have moved to blogspot, the RSS url is different from what i previously used, thus the function will not work as expected anymore. How can I work this function around the blogspot rss embed link ?? thanks

blogspot rss2.0 embed link

RSS 2.0: http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

existing function:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    function getRSS(link, number) {
        $.ajax(link, {
            accepts:{
                xml:"application/rss+xml"
            },
            dataType:"xml",
            success:function(data) {
                var blogItemArray = $(data).find("item");
                var blogItemOne = $(blogItemArray).get(0);
                var blogTitleOne = $(blogItemOne).find("title").text();
                var blogLinkOne = $(blogItemOne).find("link").text();
                var blogDescOne = $(blogItemOne).find("description").text();
                var blogImgOne = $(blogDescOne).find("img.hs-featured-image").get();
                var blogImgSrcOne = $(blogImgOne).attr("src");
                $("#blog-feed-link-" + number).attr("href", blogLinkOne);
                $(".vertAlignerImg" + number).append( $('<img class="blog-img-link-'+ number +'" />' ));
                $(".blog-img-link-" + number).attr("src", blogImgSrcOne);
                $(".vertAligner" + number).append( $('<h2 />', {text: blogTitleOne}) );
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getRSS('rsslink', "One");
        getRSS('rsslink', "Two");
    });
</script>
```

'rsslink' used to be a url that ended in /rss.xml. now it looks like the link above. thanks!

Comment: You probably can't even make the request due to CORS restrictions and would need to use a proxy. I could be wrong and you would need to check the headers of the rss url. Will get a notice in browser dev tools console if it is CORS problem

Comment: I did almost this exact thing a while back but I can't remember how I did it and I'm too tired to research it right now... But basically you just retrieve the contents of the feed to a variable, which will then be an XML formatted string. You then get yourself familiar with how to parse XML strings, just google it it's easy, and that's basically all you have to do. The RSS feed contains ALL your posts. To get the first post you'd just do something similar to (not actual code) xmlstring.tags('post')[0].tags('text')[0].value to get the text of your first ever post.

Comment: And no, there won't be any CORS problems because you're not implementing the other sites content in such a manner into your own site. You're totally free to use ajax requests to get the contents of the XML however you want with a GET request then parse that in your own site.